# Is integrity important when building anonymity?

Tags: dsa, integrity, anonymity

I was thinking about applying an anonymity process based on ECDSA signatures to anonymize blocks of information, not the public-key itself. Using a deterministic form of ECDSA to sign blocks and record only the signature hash in the block header, it is possible to not reveal the public-key. The block ownership is only revealed by requesting a re-signature of the block. Where the interested party can confirm the ownership by validating the signature, apply the hash and verify that it's equal to the one registered in the block header.

I believe this has no major security flaws. However, it's not possible to check the integrity of the block without disclosing the signature. My concern is if there is any use case that will require "anonymous integrity check"?

Comment: I think this depends entirely on the requirements that  on the system (which in turn are based on the use cases and threat model).